# Get next element's attibute in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to grab the next link's href value when hovering a series of links.  I've got this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

$( "#foo a" ).hover(function() {
    var href = $(this).next().attr('href');
    console.log(href);
});
```

Seems good to me, but I get 'undefined' in my console.

I'm new to JQuery, but not JS. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the next element is an `a` tag?

Comment: I'm coming from YUI3 where the initial selector would return a nodelist.  I guess this is different.  Trying now.

Comment: @user: The `$( "#foo a" )` returns an object with a `.length` property, and the matched elements referenced by numeric indices. But after the `.hover()` handler has been assigned, that collection is discarded. Inside the handler, `this` is simply a reference to the individual element that received the event. It would be possible to cache the initial selection, say in `foo_a`, then do `var idx=foo_a.index(this); var href=foo_a.eq(++idx).attr('href');`, but most people prefer to traverse the DOM to get to the next element.

Answer (score 3):

The [`next()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method only works on direct siblings.

You haven't provided your HTML, so I'll just guess that you need to traverse up to a common ancestor using the [`parent()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method or the [`closest()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method or something, use `.next()` to traverse to the next adjacent ancestor, then use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get the nested `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
   $('#foo a').hover(function () {
        var href = $(this).closest('li').next().find('a').attr('href');
    });
```